# How to experiment with Cassandra on the cloud with multiple nodes?

Tags: cassandra, cloud, bigdata

I want to learn Cassandra in and out. If I download it on my local laptop I can have only one node. I feel to learn Cassandra we need to have multiple nodes. Hence, option left is on cloud. Any suggestions on any cloud provider where I can experiment with minimalistic configuration and if possible for free ( for limited usage ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataStax provides a Community Edition AMI for Amazon EC2, detailed instructions [here](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/install/install_ami).

Answer (score 1):

Also datastax provides a local cluster development tool - ccm; see [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/ccm-a-development-tool-for-creating-local-cassandra-clusters) for use with the opscenter software. It is slightly out of date but still useful.